# How to arc flags to this shape in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I`m searching for solution how to arc these flags

[image]

into this shape in adobe illustrator

[image]

Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 3):

Select your flag then go to

effect > warp > arc

From there, you can edit the amount of bend as well.

Answer (score 2):

Place the shape you need as a path above the flags in the stacking order. Select the flags and the shape. Then choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object` from the menu.

[image]

Comment: Howabout ofsetting the arc for centerline and then make a brush out og the flags?

Comment: That may work too @Joojaa - but you know that `:)` There's a few possibilities if the flags are vector.. I just used the raster image in the question as a quick example.

Answer (score -2):

Manually draw circles using Path > Offset path and create a three layer circle if the flag has three layers. Then make this shape you mentioned (segment of the circle) and a clipping mask with it.

[image]

Comment: "No good solution": not true, check the other existing answer.